# URL handling when Running django with javascript framework

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-closure

I have an application written in javascript closure that runs fine on an apache server and a different application that runs on django.

I want to include the javascript application in my django project but i have click listeners connected to urls like "/places" in my closure app and that leads to confusion in my django app as it tries to use urls.py to resolve the all urls.

How can i run these sorts of apps together and specifically how can i tell django to leave some urls alone and allow the closure app deal with them?

Answer (score 0):

If you run django using apache, you can exclude them at apache level, as for media files.

```
<Location "/places">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
```